# Ruby on Rails For Displaying Real-Time Dynamic Data with fast (250 ms) updates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raspberry-pi

I am primarily a .NET programmer (C#) but for a new web application I wanted to make I decided I would try to use Ruby on Rails to learn another language.

My end goal for my application is to display the temperature from a temperature controller that is running on the server.  The temperature should update its temperature roughly every 250 ms (and ideally display and update a chart as data is updated).  The user will have the ability to interact with a heater by turning it on or off to change the temperature.

After learning some of the very basics of Ruby on Rails, I'm starting to think that Ruby on Rails is not a good match for my end goal.  I have not found a good way to update the real time data displayed on the page every 250 ms.  Am I correct in thinking Ruby on Rails is not a good framework for this application, or have I just not been searching for the right thing?  It seems great for pulling and displaying static data from a DB, but I haven't found any real time live updating examples.

Any help with doing this with Ruby on Rails, or suggestions for alternatives are appreciated.  In the end I hope to run the server from a Raspberry Pi.

Thanks!

Comment: You're not going to want to be trying to run an XHR request every 250ms, of course. Look into sockets with Rails, e.g. ActionCable: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html.

Comment: Anytime you're pinging a server you're going to find 250ms a challenge, and RoR probably won't give you the performance you want. And I'm a RoR fanatic...

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is hardly a powerhouse and I think you will struggle with 250ms regardless of framework unless it your application is only accessed on a local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this project I ended up switching to Python and Flask.  It worked great for my purposes on the Pi and had no issues with the 250 ms updates (on a local network).